# Getting Error while generating frequency of SPSS data file using python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below code to get frequency of each variable in SPSS data file however getting error, can someone suggest. please.

```
def calculateFrequency(sav):
    """ This function returns a frequency count for each variable in
    the spss data file """
    freqs = {}
    for lino, line in enumerate(sav):
        if lino == 0:
            varNames = line
        else:
            for varName in varNames:
                value = line[varNames.index(varName)]
                value = "(missing)" if value == "" else value
                try:
                    freqs[varName]
                except KeyError:
                    freqs[varName] = {}
                try:
                    freqs[varName][value] += 1
                except KeyError:
                    freqs[varName][value] = 1
    return freqs

def main(savFileName = "C:/Projects/Regression/Linear/Whiff_Deodorant_StackedData.sav"):
    with SavReader(savFileName) as sav:
        freqs = calculateFrequency(sav)
    for var, values in freqs.iteritems():
        print var, 10 * "*", var.upper(), 10 * "*"
        for val, freq in values.iteritems():
           print val, "--", freq
```

I get an error:

```
print var, 10 * "*", var.upper(), 10 * "*"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you need brackets round print:

```
print (var, 10 * "*", var.upper(), 10 * "*")
```

And likewise with the next print

```
print (val, "--", freq)
```

You might also want to look at python string formatting too.
There are different options, depending on the version, but consider looking up the `format` function:

```
print ("{} -- {}".format(val,freq))
```